# Pymoo/NSGA2 : How to interpret in output indicator column "f" indicator?

Tags: python-3.x

please I  don't understand how to interpret the "f" indicator

[image]

I read the paper:
A Running Performance Metric and Termination
The criterion for Evaluating Evolutionary Multi- and
Many-objective Optimization Algorithms

And I get to what  "ideal" and "nadir" points indicated but still, I can't interpret the "f"

Comment: I assume you're referring to [this](https://www.egr.msu.edu/~kdeb/papers/c2020003.pdf) paper and I don't know much about this topic but what it seems like to me as that "ideal" is one of possibly many optimal solutions, "nadir" would be the least optimal of the set, and therefore "f" would be any value which is in between the most and least optimal for the set of solutions. Again though, I have no idea so I might be completely wrong, sorry about that.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 1):

For each new generation, it checks first if the (potentially) new `ideal` point has moved away for enough from the previous one (by comparing the delta to a tolerance value, set at 0.0025 for multi objectives).

- If that's the case, `ideal` is printed.
- If not, the new nadir point is checked in the same way. If it is new enough, `nadir` is printed.
- If that's also not the case, but there's still a new solution found (f.e. another point in the middle on the pareto curve), then it will print `f`.

You can find this piece of code in `\pymoo\util\display\multi.py`:

```
if ind.delta_ideal > ind.tol:
    max_from = "ideal"
    eps = ind.delta_ideal
elif ind.delta_nadir > ind.tol:
    max_from = "nadir"
    eps = ind.delta_nadir
else:
    max_from = "f"
    eps = ind.delta_f

self.eps.set(eps)
self.indicator.set(max_from)
```

And some more info on the delta calculation in `\pymoo\termination\ftol.py`:

```
# calculate the change from last to current in ideal and nadir point
delta_ideal = calc_delta_norm(current["ideal"], prev["ideal"], norm)
delta_nadir = calc_delta_norm(current["nadir"], prev["nadir"], norm)
```